# Full currency on Angular

Tags: angularjs, filter, currency

I´d like to print a Full Currency Value using Angula.js.

```
<input class="receiptFrom" type="text" ng-model="receiptFrom"></input>

<label>{{ receiptValue | currency }}</label>
```

By doing this, when I input `1000`, my label prints `$1,000.00`.

I´d like it to print `One Thousand Dollars`.

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to build a custom filter - like this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build custom controller for that

Comment: yes that will check your number and convert it according to it